# Fabricjs SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED

Tags: fabricjs2

I am working on a project that requires me to load huge SVG drawings and annotations on top of it from (fabric.js) . After storing the background, I can't load it out again using loadFromJSON. It gives me SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED. Is there any way I can bypass it ?

Update:
I realized that my issue is fabric.loadSVGFromURL . As long as i run this function it would crash my browser. Just for context I am loading out CAD drawings that are converted to SVG format and the end product have to be displayed exactly to real life size. For example 11cm in the diagram should be 11cm on the screen so I stick to SVG for the measurements and scaling

Comment: You'll probably need some other format then, if loading things from that JSON is too memory-intensive.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for the swift response. I realize the issue is the fabric.loadSVGFromURL. This totally killed my browser